# Error in my c++ code using linkedlist "Stop working"

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

my code stop working in that test case, i think that the error in function Checktables but i'm not sure and i can't fix the error please help me to tun this code correctly.

[image of a test case and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhFiM.jpg)

this is a cpp file with main .cpp

```
    #include"Header.h"
string Name;
string namess;

customer::customer()
{
    name = "";
    gsize = status = 0;
    next = NULL;
}

customer::customer(string name1, int gsize1, int status1)
{
    name = name1;
    gsize = gsize1;
    status = status1;
    next = NULL;
}


waitinglist::waitinglist()
{
    chairnum =50 ;
    totalcustomers = tables = 0;
    head = tail = NULL;
}


waitinglist::waitinglist(int val) 
{
    chairnum = 50;
    totalcustomers = 0;
    tables = 0;
    head = tail = NULL;
}


void waitinglist::change()
{
    customer*temp ;
    temp = head;
    cout << "enter the name: ";
    cin >> namess;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (namess == temp->name)
            {
                if (temp->status==2)
                {
                    temp->status=1;
                    cout << "done!  " << endl ;
                    break ;
                }
            }
            else if (namess != temp->name)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }

      if (temp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "can't found! " << endl;
    }
}



void waitinglist::newcustomer()
{

    customer*tmp = new customer;
    cout << "enter the name: ";  cin >> tmp->name;
    customer*tmpo=new customer;
    tmpo=head ;
    while (tmpo != NULL)
        {

            if (tmp->name != tmpo->name)
            {
                tmpo = tmpo->next;
            }
            else if (tmp->name == tmpo->name)
            {
                cout<<"The Name already exist! " << endl ;
                cout << "enter the name: ";  cin >> tmp->name;
                tmpo=head;
            }

    }

    cout << "enter the group number: ";  cin >> tmp->gsize;
    cout << "enter the status: ";  cin >> tmp->status;
    if (head == NULL)            // linkedlist is empty
    {
        head = tail = tmp;
        totalcustomers++;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = tmp;
        tail=tail->next;
        totalcustomers++;
    }

}

void waitinglist::checktables() 
{
        float c=5.00;
        customer*temp=head;
        customer*found;
        cout<<"enter number of tables: ";
        cin >> tables ;

        while (tables>=1 && temp!=NULL)
        {
            int x;
            float y;


            y=((temp->gsize)/c);
            x=(temp->gsize)/c;

            if (tables<y)
            {
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            else if (tables>=y)
            {
                if (x==y)
                {
                    tables=tables-x ;           //   Correct Table!
                    cout<<temp->name<<endl;


                }
                else if (x!=y)
                {
                    tables=tables-(x+1);
                    cout<<temp->name<<endl;
                }

                found=temp ;
                delete found;               // Discard  
                break ;
            }

        }
    }

void waitinglist::displayall()
{
    customer *tmp;
    tmp = head;
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Empty!";
    }
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Name: " << tmp->name <<endl; 
        cout << "group number: " << tmp->gsize << endl;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void waitinglist::diplaycustomer()

{

    customer*tmp;
    tmp = head;
    cout << "enter the name: ";
    cin >> Name;

        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            if (Name == tmp->name)
            {
                cout << "the name : " << tmp->name << endl;
                cout << "the group size = " << tmp->gsize << endl;
                cout << "the status = " << tmp->status << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (Name != tmp->name)
            {
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
        }

      if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "can't found!" << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int choice;
    string name1 = "";
    int gsize1 = 0;
    int status1 = 0;
    waitinglist mylist;

    cout << "Note: 1 in status means the customer not here and 2 means the customer is here.\n";
    cout << "Select your option.\n\n";
    cout << "(1) Add a new Customer.\n";
    cout << "(2) Display information based on Name.\n";
    cout << "(3) List all Names.\n";
    cout << "(4) to change the status. \n" ;
    cout << "(5) Check tables by name. \n";
    cout << "(6) quit. \n";
    do
    {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Enter your choice: -->  ";
        cin >> choice;
        if (1 <= choice && choice <= 5)
        {
            switch (choice)
            {
            case 1:
                mylist.newcustomer();
                break;
            case 2:
                mylist.diplaycustomer();
                break;
            case 3:
                mylist.displayall();
                break;
            case 4:
                mylist.change() ;
                break;
            case 5 :
                mylist.checktables();
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Invalid choice.  Enter again.\n\n";
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (choice>6)
        {
            cout << "Invalid choice.  Enter again.\n\n";
            break;
        }

    } while (choice != 6);

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the header file .h

```
        #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;

    class customer
    {
    public:
        string name;
        int gsize;
        int status;
        customer* next;

        customer();
        customer(string,int,int);

    };

    class waitinglist
    {
    public:
        int tables; //number of occupied tables
        int chairnum;
        int totalcustomers;
        customer*head,*tail;
        waitinglist();
        waitinglist(int);
        void newcustomer();
        void diplaycustomer();
        void displayall();
        void change () ;
        void checktables();

    };
```

Comment: So choose "Debug" from that dialog in the image and start debugging.

Comment: You're on the wrong web site. This is not the web site where you get to post your entire program, with the only description being "my code stop working in that test case", without even explaining what "that test case" is, in the first place, and expect everyone to figure out why "my code stop working in that test case".

Comment: Most of this code appears unrelated to the question. There needs to be an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a stack trace for any question that involves a crash.

Comment: this is the first time for me on this site

Comment: @AhmedAlaa Why did you write all of this code, and then find out after writing all of this code that the simplest things do not work?  You're supposed to develop the code and test each piece individually.  For example, forget about the fancy input -- can you insert a name and display the names inserted  without error?  To have written all of this code, and then not know how to fix it -- there really isn't a good excuse for that happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One error is that your `checktables` function corrupts your linked list structure by calling `delete` on one of the nodes:

```
        found = temp;
        delete found;               // Discard
```

What you've just done in those lines above is to have a linked list with a broken (invalid) link in it.  Any functions that now traverses the list (like `displaytables`) will now hit the broken link, and things start to go haywire.

To delete a node from a linked list, you have to not just call `delete`, but adjust the link in `waitinglist` that used to point to that deleted node and have it point to the next node after the deleted one.

Think of it like a real chain -- if one of the links in the chain needs to be removed, you have to physically remove it, and hook the link before it to the next good link.  You didn't do this step.

I won't write the code for that, but this is what you should have seen much earlier in the development of your program.  Better yet would have been to write a singly-linked list class that adds and removes nodes correctly first.  Test it, and then once it can add and remove nodes successfully without error, then use it in your larger program.